# Fancytree lazy load exception : assertion failed: expected array of children

Tags: fancytree, lazy-loading

I have an existing tree which builds off of JSON with 3 level hierarchy.

Root ->
  ChildLevel1 ->
      ChildLevel2 (lazy =true)

The above tree data is loaded as the source on pageload., everything works fine at this point.Now - on childlevel2 I am trying to fill children on the fly as such :

```
lazyLoad: function (event, data) {              
                var json = "{children:[ {\"title\": \"Sub item\", \"lazy\": true }, {\"title\": \"Sub folder\", \"folder\": true, \"lazy\": true } ]}";
                data.result = json;
            }
```

I keep getting the following exception :

> Uncaught Error: Fancytree assertion failed: expected array of children
>       at Function.error (jquery-1.12.4.min.js:2)
>       at _assert (jquery.fancytree.js:82)
>       at jquery.fancytree.js:3242
>       at i (jquery-1.12.4.min.js:2)
>       at Object.add [as done] (jquery-1.12.4.min.js:2)
>       at Fancytree.nodeLoadChildren (jquery.fancytree.js:3229)
>       at Fancytree._callHook (jquery.fancytree.js:2289)
>       at FancytreeNode.load (jquery.fancytree.js:1229)
>       at Fancytree.nodeSetExpanded (jquery.fancytree.js:3965)
>       at Fancytree.nodeToggleExpanded (jquery.fancytree.js:4230)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing JSON string that defines an object, but the plugin requires an "array of children". Try:

```
lazyLoad: function (event, data) {              
  var res = [
    { title: "Sub item", lazy: true },
    { title: "Sub folder", folder: true, lazy: true }
    ];
  data.result = res;
}
```